# Example of C++11 template parameter misbind?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In 6.8.3 of the C++11 standard it says:

> If,
>   during parsing, a name in a template parameter is bound differently than it would be bound during a trial
>   parse, the program is ill-formed.

What is an example of a program that is ill-formed as a result of this requirement?

Comment: A "trial parse" is when you don't buy the full version of the compiler.

Comment: See comment below for the actual definition of `trial parse`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

typedef const int cint;

template <int a> struct x
{
  static cint b = 0;
};

template <> struct x<42>
{
  typedef cint b;
};

cint w = 17;

int main ()
{
  cint (w)(42), (z)(x<w>::b);

  std::cout << typeid(z).name() << std::endl;
}
```

The first declaration in `main()` needs to be disambiguated, so a trial parse is performed. During this parse, the local `w` is unknown, since the parse is purely syntactic (things are only parsed, no semantic actions are performed). Consequently, `w` is a global constant, its value is 17, `x<w>::b` is a value, and `z` is a variable.

During the real parse, semantic actions take place. Thus the name `w` is bound to the freshly declared local constant, its value is 42, `x<w>::b` becomes a type, and `z` is a function declaration.

Comment: (+1) Is the compiler required to emit a diagnostic? `gcc 4.7.2` doesn't.

Comment: "If, during parsing, a name in a  template  parameter  is  bound differently  than  it would be bound during a trial parse, the program is ill-formed.  No diagnostic is required."

Comment: Yes, it is evaluated during the trial. I don't see any requirement to throw an error, the standard says "no diagnostic is required".

Comment: ...And the standard goes on to say `[ Note: This can occur only when the name is declared earlier in the declaration. —end note ]`.

Comment: ...And, regarding the definition of `trial parse`, the standard gives an implied definition immediately prior to the text discussed above, in the same clause: `Disambiguation precedes parsing`, implying that `trial parse` is this disambiguation phase.